# How to use Rollbar.com with in Crystal Lang

Tags: crystal-lang, rollbar

I would like to use rollbar.com in my Crystal project.
I can not find crystal integration with rollbar.com or any other error trackers.

Is there a shard for the Rollbar or similar services (error tracking)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Rollbar. But there's a client for Sentry which should have similar features: https://shardbox.org/shards/raven